# Django send mail from admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to send an email to users from django admin panel and store the sent mail in the database too. I have two usertypes: 1.Staff 2. Students. When I select ***staff*** and give email, it'll send an email to all the staff who are all having "***usertype=staff***" in User model and vice versa. I found some difficulties to send the mail from the admin panel. Please some one give me an idea.

*models.py*

```
username = models.CharField()
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField()
    companyname=models.CharField()
    usertype=models.CharField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    groups = models.ManyToManyField()
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField()


class newsletter(models.Model):
    USERTYPES = (
        ('staff', 'staff'),
        ('student', 'student'),
    )
    usertype=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=USERTYPES)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message=models.TextField(blank=True)
    sentdate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

*admin.py*

```
admin.site.register(newsletter)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps an [admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) would be suitable.

See also: [sending email in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/).

Answer (score 0):

Well Looking at the doc I found that you can add views to your admin site

[admin doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites)

[extending get_urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) function